# Soapcall without parameters results in a blank screen

Tags: php, soap

When do a soapcall on a function that does not require parameters my screen turns blank. While when I run a soapcall that does require parameters I receive data/errors.

```
try {
    $r = $this->c->__soapCall($func, $params);
} catch( Exception $e ) {
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

$this->c = of course the soapclient who connets correctly.

Also I get no errors in my log or returned to my screen. There are no syntax errors.

Comment: Are you sure you have error_reporting set to E_ALL?

Comment: Is there anyway I can verify to what error_reporting is set at a certain point? I put error_reporting(E_ALL) on the first line of the class. So it should be E_ALL right?

Comment: Unless some code below that modifies it, it should be E_ALL yes. Sorry I can't help you any more than that :\

Comment: I'm sure error_reporting is set to E_ALL. I'm doing an echo of error_reporting() right before I execute the call and it returns a 6143. Still no errors beyond the call.

Comment: `error_reporting` *alone* is useless -- do you also have `display_errors` enabled?  Try `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Display errors did the trick. The error_reporting alone return the value of what error_reporting is set to. That's why I used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that $parameters were null, which is not allowed.