# function __soapCall() without second parameter

Tags: php, soap

I want to call this function without the second parameter. http://php.net/manual/de/soapclient.soapcall.php

The first one is the function, but the function I want to call has no parameters. So how do I call that function as well?

I found nearly the same question right here, but that doesnt solve my problem. [Soapcall without parameters results in a blank screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402946/soapcall-without-parameters-results-in-a-blank-screen)

Thanks for your help.

Edit: This doesnt work: array(), but this: array("":"")

Comment: but second parameter is optional by documentation. why you need it at all ? ;)

Comment: I tried array() as the second parameter and get "Array" as response. Also tried without 2nd parameter and got nothing back.